# Modeling changed amount of shifts per day in FirebaseDB

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm creating a small shift management application using Android Studio and Google's Firebase Database.

I'd like it to allow the Admin to select a date (from the calendar) and set , amongst other parameters (such as number of employees per shift, start and end time per shift , etc) the number of shifts for that date.

This is what I had in mind when first starting this project:

```
{                                                                
  "accounts" : {
                 "admin" : {
                             "email" : "admin@gmail.com",
                             "password" : 123
                           }
                 "user1" : {
                             "email" : "user1@gmail.com",
                             "password" : 234
                           }
              },                                                   
 "config" : {
                "shiftsPerDay" : {
                                   "Shift 2" : {
                                                 "end" : "00:00",
                                                 "name" : "eveningShift",
                                                 "numOfEmps" : 2,
                                                 "start" : "16:00",
                                                 "wage" : 0
                                              },
                                  "Shift 1" : {
                                                "end" : "16:00",
                                                "name" : "morningShift",
                                                "numOfEmps" : 3,
                                                "start" : "8:00",
                                                "wage" : 0
                                              }
                                 }
           }
```

But this will only work if the number of shifts per day is fixed. 
I want each date to have its own number of shifts (e.g. 1/18-3; 1/19-4; 1/20-1; ..1/25-3; 1/26-2 and so on).

Is there a better way of modeling such a structure using Firebase?

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: updated as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store separate shifts for each day, add a level for those days to your JSON structure:

```
"config" : {
    "shiftsPerDay" : {
        "20190118": {
            "Shift 2" : {
                         "end" : "00:00",
                         "name" : "eveningShift",
                         "numOfEmps" : 2,
                         "start" : "16:00",
                         "wage" : 0
                      },
           "Shift 1" : {
                        "end" : "16:00",
                        "name" : "morningShift",
                        "numOfEmps" : 3,
                        "start" : "8:00",
                        "wage" : 0
                      }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you